# Extending the Publish and Transport processes

Tags: web8, web8.5, 2011-sp1, publishtransaction, transport

In [THIS](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/howto-tackle-integrations-in-sdl-tridion-2011) article, the following is stated:

> The Publish process and the Transport process can both be extended using the **IPublishTransactionHandler** and **ITransportPackageItemHandler** interfaces respectively.

My question is, are these extension points still available in 8 or 8.5 (the official docs only mention custom resolvers and custom renderers)? If yes, where can I find these interfaces and where should they be plugged into?

Looking at the 2011 chm files, I am unable to find them. In *SDL Tridion 2011 Content Delivery ASP.NET API* there is a `Com.Tridion.Distribution.Transport.Transaction` namespace which sounds promising, but looking at the members I can't find anything useful. Nor do I see the interfaces in any of the 8.5 API-s.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mentioned extension points are “semi-public” CM Publisher extension points.

This means that these are technically speaking public APIs, but they are intentionally kept a bit under the radar, because they are considered “advanced” customizations (not expected to be needed for typical use cases).

So, the question for you is: which use cases do you have in mind that might require those extension points?

Comment: Yeah it's a very atypical use case indeed, unfortunately I am not permitted to disclose it at this point. Btw. I managed to find the interfaces and where to plug them, but for the sake of keeping them under the radar I won't document them here.